# What is the most elegant way of counting files in a folder in Python?

Tags: python, file, directory, numbers

I'm very new to Python and I'm currently learning it.

As the title says: what is the most elegant, concise, efficient and python-esque way of counting files in a folder?

Let's assume a folder containing only files and no subfolders.

By (naively) applying what I've learned, I've come up with this:

```
from os import walk

num_files = -1

for (dir_path, dir_names, file_names) in walk(image_file_path):
    for fn in file_names:
        num_files += 1
```

It doesn't look that elegant and I realize that *fn* remains unused throughout the iteration. In addition, that *num_files = -1* is the farthest thing from elegant.

So what is a better way to write this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try os.listdir

```
import os
len(os.listdir(image_file_path))
```

Comment: Thanks! Super clean.

Comment: @Polcio, Note, that `os.listdir()` returns list with filenames, not full path to files.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the following is the most Pythonic modern answer:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(image_file_path)
num_files = sum(1 for x in path.iterdir() if x.is_file())
```

Comment: How is this "more Pythonic" than, say, `len(os.listdir(image_file_path))`?

Comment: @DeepSpace `pathlib` is a more modern approach than `os`. Also in case OP's assumption that no subfolders are present gets violated that gives the wrong answer.

Comment: @orlp, why not `sum(x.is_file() for x in path.iterdir())`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght That would work, and on a different day maybe I would've written that. Some people get a bit iffy around implicit bool -> int conversion though.

Comment: @orlp, ah, I thought that there's something related to performance

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like `glob`:

```py
from glob import glob
num_files = len(glob(dir_name.rstrip('/') + '/*'))
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between glob and os? Is one more modern than the other?

Comment: @Polcio `glob` is actually meant to search for files with a regex. Using `*`, I'm asking it to list all files. You can customize the pattern to get only the files you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by get all files and folder inside of spesific path like this `os.listdir("./")`. than filter all files with list comprehension like this `[i for i in os.listdir("./") if os.path.isfile(i)]`. and for the end count the object you have in your list. if we put it all together it look like this `len([i for i in os.listdir("./") if os.path.isfile(i)])`

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns just filenames without root dir, so your code will work only if you execute script from same directory with files. Alternatively you can use `os.scandir()`: `sum(map(os.path.isfile, os.scandir("./")))`.

Answer (score -1):

try list comprehension

```
total_files = sum(len(dirData[2]) for dirData in walk(image_file_path))
```

Comment: OP's original code is more pythonic/idiomatic than this suggestion, partly because this code does not even work. Did you mean `sum([len(file_names) for (dir_path, dir_names, file_names) in walk('.')])` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace i was only suggesting a oneliner, that's all.

Comment: But it does **not** work. It tries to sum a list of functions.

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks, there was a mistake, its fixed and updated. It should work now.